# My callback function isn't getting called

Tags: node.js, callback

My callback function is not getting called.
I made two modules:

1. `input.js` - it uses `readline` to take some messages from the user on the console. it has a `getMessages()` function that takes the user input and stores the messages in an array.
2. `main.js` - here I call `getMessages()` and have a callback function so that when the function is done executing, I can print the array.

There seems to be nothing wrong with the input module as I am getting the array at the end of `getMessages()`. My callback, however, is not getting called.
I verified it by inserting `console.log` and checking the output at various stages. Once the `getMessages()` is executed, the program stops. I may be missing out on something as I am completely new to Node. Appreciate any help.

```js
// input.js
var messages = [];

function getMessages() {
  const readline = require("readline");

  rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
  });

  rl.setPrompt("enter a message, press 0 when done : ");
  rl.prompt();

  rl.on("line", function(msg) {

    if (msg == 0) {
      rl.close();
    } else {
      messages.push(msg);
      rl.prompt();
    }

  });

  rl.on("close", function() {
    console.log("returning array : ", messages);
    return messages;
  });
}
module.exports.getMessages = getMessages;
```

```js
// main.js
const input = require("./input");

input.getMessages(function(err, messages) {
  console.log("Your messages are : ", messages, messages.length);
});
```

```
PS D:\files\workspaces\tameOfThrones\node> node .\main.js
enter a message, press 0 when done : abc

enter a message, press 0 when done : def

enter a message, press 0 when done : ghi

enter a message, press 0 when done : jkl

enter a message, press 0 when done : mno

enter a message, press 0 when done : 0

returning array :  [ 'abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'mno' ]

PS D:\files\workspaces\tameOfThrones\node>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function getMessages, does not have a parameter as a callback.

Meaning,

```
function getMessages(){}
```

While:

```
input.getMessages(function(err, messages){

console.log("Your messages are : ", messages, messages.length);

});
```

You need to :

```
 function getMessages(callback){
    //call callback according to your logic

 }
```

Comment: you mean to say that if I declare the function as - function getMessages(callback){...}, with the keyword "callback" in it, it would mean that this function has a callback associated with it?

Comment: also, what I'm trying to do here is that once getMessages() is done taking input, the callback should be called where I could print out the messages. am I coding it the write way?

Comment: @RohitMishra - Callback is just a parameter passed to the function. You can name it any way you deem fit. What my answer details is the fact that you forgot to write on the function's signature that it accepts a parameter. When the inner logic of your getMessages method is done, you can just write callback() and that will invoke the method you passed in as the parameter callback. If you want to read more about callbacks, you can do it [here](https://codeburst.io/javascript-what-the-heck-is-a-callback-aba4da2deced). Also, if my answer helped you, please mark it as such.

Comment: I still somehow don't seem to get it. Thanks for the reply though. I will read the article you've shared the link to. :)

Comment: this article you suggested cleared things for me. thanks man. cheers :)